# Saving networks and weights fro EncogModel

Tags: networking, save, drive, encog

I was able to create a network, train it and evaluate it using EncogModel. However, i would like to be able to save the network, training and weights, so that every time i run it, i dont have to train it. I found encog persistence, but I'm having a hard time putting encogmodel and percistence together. is there any sample codes available? If not, how could this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Used:

```
SerializeObject.Save(string path, network);
```

and

```
EncogUtility.SaveEGB( FileInfo path , data);
```

`EncogDirectoryPersistance.SaveObject(FileInfo f,network)` seemed to not support NEAT, it kept returning an error.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button; you may want to include a link to this one for context. Or you may star this question as a favorite to be notified of any new answers. Once you have sufficient reputation, [you may also upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) it.