# EncogDirectoryPersistence Error when attempting to load a network trained in Encog 3.3

Tags: load, persistence, encog

I trained a temporal neural network in Encog 3.3.Then I went to C# and Attempted to call it with the following Code:

```
class Program
{
    public static  BasicNetwork LoadEG(FileInfo dir)
{
    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(" File Does Not Exists...");
       return null;
    }
    else
    {
        var netWork1 = new BasicNetwork();
            netWork1 = ( BasicNetwork)EncogDirectoryPersistence.LoadObject(dir);
        return netWork1;
    }

}
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        var fileName =new FileInfo( @"C:\Users\YandyChang\EncogProjects\Temporal Test More Variables\DataSet_train.eg");
        var trainingFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\YandyChang\EncogProjects\Temporal Test More Variables\DataSet_train.egb");
       var network=LoadEG(fileName);
       var trainingSet = (IMLDataSet)EncogUtility.LoadEGB2Memory(trainingFile);
       double errorRate= network.CalculateError(trainingSet);
       Console.WriteLine(" Error rate of training: "+errorRate);
       Console.WriteLine("InputSize:"+trainingSet.InputSize);
       Console.WriteLine("Ideal Size: "+trainingSet.IdealSize);
       Console.WriteLine("Training: "+trainingSet.Supervised);
       Console.ReadLine();
       trainingSet.Close();

    }
}
```

I get the Following Error when trying to load the EG File:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in encog-core-cs.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Has anyone had the same problem, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: how you created eg file?

Comment: Trained and saved the network to an EG file using Encog WorkBench. But it can also be coded, there is one or two examples in the internet and the encog 3 manual( gives you a good explanation)... Also, look up in here,  where I think I answered one of my own questions on how to save To .SER and .EGB. NEAT networks I could not save it to EG file, but to a SER file. Hope this helps...

Comment: Here is a link to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28489900/4159798